# How to add a cron job with crontab -e

Tags: cron, centos7, aide

My system is centos 7.4.
After `crontab -e`,I add

```
MAILTO=root
30 4 * * * root /usr/sbin/aide --check
```

Then I receive email as below:

```
From: "(Cron Daemon)" <root@mail.mydomain.com>
To: root@mail.mydomain.com
Subject: Cron <root@myserver> root /usr/sbin/aide --check
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
Precedence: bulk
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_SESSION_ID=37>
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0>
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <MAILTO=root>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=root>
Message-Id: <20190300432001.5EC7524C51@mail.mydomain.com>
Date: Fri,  1 Mar 2019 04:32:01

/bin/sh: root: command not found
```

I checked `/var/log/aide/aide.log` is empty, there's no any information in `messages` and `secure`.It seemed my crontab script is somewhere wrong.
I just want to receive `aide --check` report,where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you must exec is this:

```
MAILTO=root
30 4 * * * /usr/sbin/aide --check
```

Cron interpret `root` as command. The original cron records differ from those in `cron.daily` and so on directories because the standard `cron` records are per user, not per specific time